# How can a module depend on a shaded jar without redundant dependence?

Tags: maven

I have a project with two modules as below:

project

-- module1 (shaded jar， depend on lib A,B)

-- module2  (war)

Module2 depends on module1. And module1 packages to a shaded jar with maven shade plugin. Module2 packages to a war which depends on module1.

When I try to execute mvn package, it produces a war contains the shaded jar but also the dependent libs which the shades jar depends(A,B).

That's strange.  How can I make the war contain shaded jar only but not the dependent libs? Any advice, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Maven doesn't know that `module1` has been shaded. When it tries to resolve the dependencies for `module2`, it looks at module1's POM and sees all its dependencies, which are subsequently included in module2's WAR file.

You can fix this in three different ways:

- Don't shade `module1`. You haven't stated why you need to do this, but if you can avoid it, this is what I would recommend.
- When specifying `module1` as a dependency to `module2`, exclude all its dependencies:

Like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <!-- 
       Pre-Maven 3.2.1: Repeat groupId and artifactId for all 
       direct dependencies of module1.

       Maven 3.2.1 and onwards: substitute the '...' below with '*'
    -->
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

- Introduce an attached Maven assembly to `module1` and apply the exclusion trick above. I just tried this and it worked for me. In my experience, when depending on customized "bundles", assemblies tend to work more reliably than shaded artifacts. And then you don't have to do the shading at all.

Comment: yep, I exclude all the libs when module2 depends on module1. But it cause a compile problem(class not found cause of exclude). I think it's better excluding the libs in the war package phase.

Comment: What if I made an attached shaded jar with classifier, and module2 depends on the shaded jar? @Daniel

Comment: Module1 is shaded cause it's a hadoop job module containing all the hadoop jobs that module2 need to execute. I make a fatjar with all the dependences to avoid submitting job on yarn with class not found exception.

Comment: For one thing, mvn package phases recognized the shaded jar but didnt recognize the reduce-shaded-pom, why? @Daniel

Comment: depending on a classifier does not work, because classifiers share the pom with the main artifact, and thus all dependencies.

Comment: The problem with dependeny-reduced-pom is that it does not update the actual `MavenProject` in memory (at least not fully).

Comment: @Daniel: for newer maven versions `<groupId>*</groupId>` and `<artifactId>*</artifactId>` can be used.

Comment: @blackbuild cool. Great tip! I guess I'm old-school. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: @blackbuild  exclude the libs will cause a class not found exception in the compile phase. Why? Actually all the classes are already in the fat jar.